# C- Character Push and Pop operation

Tags: c, arrays, stack, strcat

```
Stack create(int c)
{
    Stack S=(Stack)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    S->size=c;
    S->top=-1;
    S->array=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*c);

    return S;
}

Stack makeEmpty(void)
{
    Stack *S1=create(100);
    S1[0]->top=-1;
    return S1;
}

char pop(Stack S)
{
    return S->array[S->top--];
};

int main(void)
{
    Stack *S1;
    S1=makeEmpty();
    int j;
    int k=0;
    char result[30];
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        char result1=pop(S1);
        strcat(result, result1);
        k++;
    }
}
```

I skipped some parts, like `typedef struct stack Stack`;
What I wanted to do was pop out elements from the stack while for-loop works. Then, store those elements in a new array which is `result`. To check whether it works or not, I printed out but I had a runtime error. How to store the element and how to print it out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but concentrate on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) more urgently.  "I had a runtime error" is an appalling explanation of what went wrong.  What really happened, and what had you input?  The code you show doesn't define the structure type, nor show how data is pushed.  Most often, you should predecrement the stack pointer, but it depends...  And the problem is as likely to be in the code you haven't shown as in the code you do show.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Besides, the signature of `strcat` is `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`. You are passing a `char`, your compiler must have warned you about it.

Comment: How does your `pop()` function tell you there wasn't a character to pop?  You haven't shown how things get pushed, but I do see that you have `-1` in the `top` for an empty stack, so the `S->top--` isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: In `makeEmpty` you have a syntax error, `S1[0]->top=-1;` is wrong, it should be `S1[0].top=-1;`. Do you compile your stuff before posting it here? Do you read the compiler error? Besides, doing this is pointless, the `create` call already assigns `-1` to `top`.

Comment: I tried both one, but S1[0].top=-1 made a compile error.

Comment: you requested for memory but didn't release it. And [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made copy&paste of your code, and it doesn't get compiled. I think that
you are either not posting your actually code nor you don't bother to compile and read the compiler warnings. It's rather difficult to help you. Here some things I noticed:

1.
`create` must return a pointer to `Stack`, not the object.

```
Stack *create(int c)
{
    Stack *S = malloc(sizeof *S);

    S->size=c;
    S->top=-1;
    S->array = malloc(c);

    return S;
}
```

2.
Same goes for `makeEmpty`

```
Stack *makeEmpty(void)
{
    Stack *S1=create(100);
    S1->top=-1;
    return S1;
}
```

3.
`pop` should get a pointer to `Stack`, not the object

```
char pop(Stack *S)
{
    return S->array[S->top--];
};
```

Here you should check whether there are elements on your stack. `int pop(Stack *S, char *val)` where it returns 1 and writes on `*val` on
success, and returns 0 otherwise would be better.

4.
Judging from your `pop` you are pushing `char` only. I don't get what you
are trying to do with `strcat`. Either way, you are doing `strcat` wrong. You
are declaring a stack with 100 spaces, but you are only declaring 30 spaces
for `result`. What if you have more than 31 elements on your stack? I know
that you are only inspecting 2 elements but it's easy to overlook that and
expand it to go through all the stack without changing the memory requirements
for `result`.

Also `strcat` is a function that works with C-Strings, that means it expects
C-Strings. A C-String **must** be `\0` terminated, yours are not. You have
something that looks like a C-String but it's not. If you insist on using
`strcat`, the you should do it like this:

```
for(j=0; j<2; j++)
{
    char result1[] = { pop(S1), 0 };
    strcat(result, result1);
}
```