# Push pop stack operation in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strcmp

I tried to make a stack push pop operations with storing values from pop in an array. I have a few questions for this code.
1. Does the initialization part work well? When compiling, it seems there is no problem but I'm still curious.
2. Does the deletion part also work well? Although, I typed `!`, it seems it doesn't goes to `else if(strcmp (str[i], "!")==0)` part.
3. How could store values after pop operations? I want to store it as an array format but when I print out after storing them in the array, runtime error occured.
**Here's the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct stack *Stack;

struct stack {
    char *array;
    int size;
    int top;
};//making stack


Stack create(int c);
Stack makeEmpty(void);//initialization
int isEmpty(Stack S)
{
    if(S->top==-1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
};
void push(char X, Stack S)
{
    S->array[++S->top]=X;
};
char pop(Stack S)
{
    return S->array[S->top--];
};
void deleteStack(Stack S)
{
    while (S->top>=0)
    {
        free(S->array[S->top]);
        S->top--;
    }

};

int main (void)
{
    Stack S1=makeEmpty();
    char input[100], result[30], result1;
    char *word;
    int cnt=0,cnt2=0, temp=0, k=0, i,j,l;
    word=strtok(input, " ");
    char *str[20];

    while(1){
        if(fgets(input,100,stdin)){
            word=strtok(input, " ");//get input and tokenize
            cnt=0;
            while (word!=NULL)
            {
                str[cnt]=strdup(word);
                cnt++;
                word=strtok(NULL," ");  
            }       
        }

        for (i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(str[i],"(")==0 && (isEmpty(S1)==0))
            {
                push(str[i],S1);
                l++;
            }
            else if(strcmp(str[i],")")==0)
            {
                temp++;
                for(j=0; j<cnt2; j++)
                {
                    char result1=pop(S1);
                    result[k] =result1;
                    printf("%s ", result[k]);//This the place where I got runtime error
                    k++;
                }
                pop(S1);
                cnt2=0;     
            }
            else if(strcmp (str[i], "!")==0)
            {
                printf("in\n");
                deleteStack(S1);
                return 0;
            }

            else 
            {
                if  (isEmpty(S1)==1)
                {

                    if (l!=0)
                    {
                        push(str[i],S1);

                        if (strcmp(str[i],"(")!=0)
                        {
                            cnt2++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


Stack create(int c)
{
Stack S=(Stack)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    S->size=c;
    S->top=-1;
    S->array=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*c);

    return S;
}

Stack makeEmpty(void)
{
    Stack S1=create(100);
    S1[0].top=-1;
    return S1;
}
```

Comment: You're first 2 questions are too generic: how is "well" defined, for starters? Besides, you're asking 3 different question in one question. Only the last question has some merit, but it'd be better if you focus your code and question on just that: limit your code to a minimal example producing that error, and let us know what you've already done to debug your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C- Character Push and Pop operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069933/c-character-push-and-pop-operation)

Comment: Also practical reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: 1/ Don't cast `malloc` in C (and don't use `malloc` in C++; more on that if you ask about it). 2/ Don't hide levels of pointer indirection behind `typedef`. 3/ Your data structure logic should generally not decide whether or not `malloc` and `free` are used; in the world of C, that decision should go the person writing the entry point (`main`, or what-not for whatever dynamic library). As your project is presumably intended for use by other people, you should leave the decision with them as to how to expand their arrays... and... the best tool for the job is likely `pipe`, not `malloc`.

Comment: @pablo Thank you for your previous comments. I tried to follow yours, but it still doesn't work. So I thought the problem would not just in storing array from pop but also in other parts. As you commented, I changed S into *S by using typedef on top of the code. I thought it would be the same meaning as you commented but if it is not, could you explain to me..? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Use `pipe` to create two file descriptors. Write to one when you're pushing, read from the other when you're popping. This tool was given to you for a reason. It may not be fast, but my guess is it'll compete with this, and scale far beyond... with less than half of the code...

Comment: @Sebivor just so you know `pipe` is not standard C but `POSIX`. Also, going to the operating system every time for a simple stack sounds a waste of resources.

Comment: @Sebivor: I believe a pipe would give a FIFO (first-in, first-out) discipline, not a stack (LIFO — last-in, first-out) discipline.  There's a reason `mkfifo()` is used to create 'named pipes'.

Comment: It's very important that you improve the indentation of your code. The current formatting makes it difficult to read and, ergo, difficult for you to find good help.

Comment: @Richard I've made an edit for that. My edit is still on the peer review queue.

Comment: @Pablo: Good work - I've voted for its approval. However, it's always good to remind new users that the best way of getting value out of a question is to put work into making a good question. (Incidentally, had I edited this myself, I'd probably have converted the bracing to [K&R style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K&R) - I find it works better in the limited space SO gives.)

Comment: @Richard I try not to change to much of the user's style, but at least make the indentions consistent. I see I've missed one line in `create` though.

Comment: Note that the semicolons after the close brace `}` at the end of a function is not part of the function syntax.  Strictly, it marks the end of an empty declaration at file scope.  Simply remove them.  The semicolon is needed after variable and and type declarations or definitions at file scope.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for updating my code. I know that about the semicolons. It's just that I've been writing a lot of JavaScript lately and within my company's coding style are stuff like this `$scope.myfunf = function() { ... };` and I did it out of habit without realizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have again some things wrong. Before you create new threads with
similar content, stick to one thread.

In your code you also never check if `malloc` fails. It's always better to do that. For simplicity I've omitted these checks in my suggestions.

1.
Why do you do `S1[0].top=-1;` in `makeEmpty`? `create` already does that and writing in that way (instead of `S1->top = -1`) makes the code hard to interpret, because it could mean that you are treating the result of `create` as an array of `Stack`s. It's not wrong, it makes harder for us to interpret your intentions.

```
Stack makeEmpty(void)
{
    Stack S1=create(100);
    return S1;
}
```

is enough.

2.
In `push` and `pop` you have to check first if the operations are valid. That
means:

- for `push`: check that you still have space to do the operation
- for `pop`: check that you have at least one element on the stack.

The code could be:

```
int isFull(Stack S)
{
    return (S->size - 1 == S->top);
}

int push(char X, Stack S)
{
    if(isFull(S))
        return 0;

    S->array[++S->top]=X;
    return 1;
}

int pop(Stack S, char *val)
{
    if(isEmpty(S))
        return 0;

    *val = S->array[S->top--];
    return 1;
}
```

I changed the signatures of these functions to let the user know **if** the
operation were successful. Otherwise you have no idea and you end up with
undefined values. In main your should change the `pop` calls as well:

```
char el;
pop(S1, &el);
```

3.
What do you want `deleteStack` to do: reset the stack or free the memory? You
are mixing those in a bad way.

If you want to reset (meaning to pop all elements at once), then all you have
to do is set `top = -1`. You don't have to free `array`. If you do, then you
need to reallocate memory for `array` again.

When using `free` you can only pass to `free` the same pointer
you've got from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`. In your code you are passing a
8 bit integer as a pointer address and freeing that, that will make your
program crash 100% of the time.

```
void deleteStack(Stack S)
{
    S->top = -1;
}
```

If you want to free the memory

```
void freeStack(Stack S)
{
    free(S->array);
    free(S);
}
```

**but** that also means that you cannot access the stack any more. Note that I
changed the name of the function to make it more clear its intention.

If you use my suggestions, you have to change them in `main` as well,
specially the `pop`s.

---

**EDIT**:
Sebivor's quote from the comments:

> Don't hide levels of pointer indirection behind `typedef`

Yes, that also makes the code hard to read. In my suggestions I didn't change that, but I definitely would change

```
typedef struct stack Stack;
```

and in every function that has `Stack S` as argument change it to `Stack *S`.  (See also [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/) — the short answer is 'No'.)